# How to access BigCommerce internalapi?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to download (backup) images that customers upload for products that take custom logos (these are typically JPG, PNG, PDF, etc.) These customer files are downloadable by clicking on a hyperlink in the BigCommerce admin page for the order in question. The link is not a link to the image path but instead, a link to a service that sends the file to the browser. In other words, you have to be authenticated into the admin site to download the file.  The URL looks like this:

https://mystore.com/internalapi/v1/orders/383945/products/251438/attributes/561518/download

https://mystore.com/internalapi/v1/orders/{order id}/products/{lineItem id}/attributes/{option id}/download

These are easily constructed in the API itself for a given order. If I use the link in a browser tab while I'm logged into the admin site, the file downloads.

But what I am trying to write an app to automatically download all the files (there are thousands). When I try to use this URL in an app, I get a authentication error. I tried at first using my regular API credentials but then used the credentials to log into the admin site. Both give me an authentication error.

I could not find anything documented on this so-called "internalapi." Anyone ever try to use this "internal" API that is used by the admin site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe authentication is cookie based for that internal API, but there could be problems with using our non-publicly documented internal APIs in production, i.e. we may make future updates that would be breaking changes.

Images attached to orders through a file upload option also get copied to WebDAV, in the `dav/product_images/configured_products` folder. Another way to do this could be to use a WebDAV client library like [easywebdav](https://github.com/amnong/easywebdav) to connect and download the files.

Comment: Thanks  Karen. I can see all the files there and this gives me a clear path to a solution.